# Custom alert with Checkbox - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying get a alert pop up that has a checkbox in it, where the user needs to check that and click submit to proceed forward.

I used a *div tag* to define the alert message that has to be displayed on the alert and then wrote some java script to return the value.

my div tag with alert message:

```
<div id="confirm_popup" style="color:red">
  <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" /> Check in to confirm the following actions to take place and click OK
  <div style="margin-top: 15px; font-weight: bold; color:red; ">
    <p>* You will not be able to make additional changes to your current reporting period. It is very important to review your credits. </p>
    <p>* A new two-year reporting period tab will open. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $('#close_record').submit(function() {
    var status = false
      $("#confirm_popup").html("Hi message!!!").dialog({
          modal: true,
          title: 'Alert Message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
          width: 'auto', resizable: false,
          buttons: {
              Ok: function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  if ($('#myCheckBox').is(":checked")){
                    status = true
                  }
              },
          },
          close: function (event, ui) {
              $(this).remove();
          }
      });

    if(status == true){
      return true
    }
    else {
      false
    }
  })

</script>
```

close_record is the id of the form where the I have my submit button. I am using the form submit action to trigger the javascript for the pop up.

But for some reason this isn't working.. I have tried all the possible ways that I can think of and nothing has helped.. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Did you add the [jQuery UI library](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) that uses `dialog`?

Comment: Also, where are you placing the script? Is your form in the DOM before you bind the `submit` event to `#close_record`?

Comment: The code is asynchronous and you treat it as synchronous. The code can not return from the dialog. You need to handle everything from the Ok and Close methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fire the `submit` event just after dialog closes.

In the OK function you need to detect the checkbox and then make something like this:

```
  $('#yourForm').trigger('submit');
```

Avoid variables in asynchronous methods, the value will not be that you need or what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead :

```
<form id="close_record">
    <input type="checkbox" style="display: none" id="myCheckBoxForm" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" />
</form>
<div id="confirm_popup" style="color:red">
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckBox" />Check in to confirm the following actions to take place and click OK
    <div style="margin-top: 15px; font-weight: bold; color:red; ">
        <p>* You will not be able to make additional changes to your current reporting period. It is very important to review your credits.</p>
        <p>* A new two-year reporting period tab will open.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the JS :

```
 $('#close_record').submit(function (e) {

      if ($('#myCheckBoxForm').is(":checked")) {
          return true;
      } else {
          e.preventDefault();
      }

      $("#confirm_popup").dialog({
          modal: true,
          title: 'Alert Message',
          zIndex: 10000,
          autoOpen: true,
          width: 'auto',
          resizable: false,
          buttons: {
              Ok: function () {
                  $(this).dialog("close");
                  $('#myCheckBoxForm').prop('checked', $('#myCheckBox').prop('checked'));
              },
          }
      });

  })
```

Comment: Mind you, that you will need jQuery UI for this. In case you do not have the library.

Comment: I have tried this code @thegeekrv. but still no pop up and yes I have jQuery ui configured.

Comment: I don't have any checkbox on the form to check for the first if condition in your JS. I only need it when the user clicks on the "go" button

Comment: Yes I know, that's why the one in the form is hidden :)